# Expanding Greenplum cluster (segment size diminish)

Tags: greenplum

If I add new server (or several) to Greenplum Cluster (1 master, 3 nodes, 2 primary segments per server).
Will segment size diminish or will not grow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the same data volume after adding a new server, the segment size will be smaller, assuming you re-distributed your data.

i.e.  If we have perfect distribution today 33.3% of your data is on each of your nodes.  If you add a 4th node, 25% of your data will be on each node.

Distribution is not always perfect across nodes, but the example above is to illustrate the point.

Does this answer your question?